# Finding Dynamic controls in other Rows of a Repeater

Tags: c#, repeater, web-controls

I'm using a repeater to create a dynamic, database driven form.

Part of the required functionality is to be able to have dynamically driven drop down lists that depend on the values from previously selected drop downs to generate their values.

So If i'm creating a drop down list control and adding it to a row and assigning it an id, and i go to the next row, how do I get the value from the control in the previous row?

This is what I'm trying, but the .FindControl is returning null every time.

```
DropDownList toParentDDL = (DropDownList)rptDynamicForm.FindControl("ParentControlID");
```

The ID's are being set properly, and the id being placed in the find control method is proper as well.

Just another thought... When I'm adding the controls to the repeater, i'm doing so as such:

```
e.Item.FindControl("pnlQuestionAnswer").Controls.Add(toDropDown);
```

could it be that it is nested inside the panel?

To clear up any confusion.  These controls are being created on  ItemDataBound.

Solution:

Thanks to Tim's help.  I finally realized what the problem was.  I was looking for the control inside the repeater, and the repeater itself doesnt contain the control, the ITEMS contain the control I was looking for, and even though the items are in the repeater, it doesn't look IN the items.  (I had it in my head that .findcontorl works like .find in jquery, which it doesn't)

to Fix the issue I simply did:

```
                    foreach (RepeaterItem toItem in rptDynamicForm.Items)
                    {
                        DropDownList toParentDDL = (DropDownList)toItem.FindControl("ParentControlID");

                        }
```

so now as long as it doesnt return null, it will contain the correct control.

Comment: Can you make sure that the name of the control in your FindControl("") is spelled correctly C# the case is important..

Comment: the values that are assigned to the id, and are used in the find control are pulled from the database... i have verified at runtime that the values are identical.

Comment: You have to check your view source and identify diff between both ID

Comment: How are you creating these controls? Normally you would use the [Repater's ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to add your controls and change the repeater's DataSource to let it create these controls automatically.

Comment: @Tim I'm returning a dataset from the database that contains the details for the control and i'm creating the controls and adding them to the item's questionanswer panel.

Comment: @Sanjay the Id's are correct.

Comment: Patrick based on your last note I am deleting my answer you never made it clear within which Event you were expecting to do this.. sorry..

Comment: What is `rptDynamicForm`? If it's the repeater itself, it's obvious why this doesn't work: the NamingContainer of your dynamic controls(in ItemTemplate) are the [RepeaterItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.aspx) and not the Repeater. You should definitely add more source code, otherwise it's difficult to see what you're doing(what is `ParentControlID` etc.).

Comment: no problem.  i just assumed that the wording of the question lent itself towards the itemdatabound event... regardless.. I do not understand why the findcontrol method wouldn't work in the on item databound event.

Comment: @Tim... but doesnt repeateritem refer to the direct parent of the control.  since findcontrol is not recursive, and i'm looking in the same item that this control is, it won't find it anyway because the control is NOT in the same item... it is in one of the previous items.

Comment: @Patrick: then you need to get the reference on the previous RepeaterItem to find a nested control. But you cannot find it via the Repeater.

Comment: would/could i iterate through each item that currently exists in the repeater until i find the control on each item until i find the correct parent?

Comment: @Tim... I considered that, but I have no guarantee that its going to be in the "first" previous item... it could be stored in ANY of the items that have come before the current item... so are you saying that findcontrol does no type of drilldown into any of the controls contained by the parent?

Comment: aha! precisely.  Thank you for talking me thorugh that one... I was expecting .findcontrol in c# to work more like .find in jquery... I was able to itterate thorugh the items and find the control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot search the repeater to find a control in one of its ItemTemplates. Their [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) are their [RepeaterItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.aspx) not the `Repeater` itself. This makes sense since every item contains controls with the same ID as the previous/next item.

Therefore you need to get a reference to the previous item to find your control:

```
protected void rptDynamicForm_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   switch (e.Item.ItemType) {
       case ListItemType.Item:
       case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
          if (e.Item.ItemIndex != 0) {
             DropDownList toParentDDL = 
                (DropDownList)rptDynamicForm.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex - 1].FindControl("ParentControlID");
          }
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i get it now... unfortunately getting simply the previous row won't work because for this particular form I will have 4 rows that will derive their parent value from a single field.  regardless... this IS the correct answer.